# Sed replacing string with quotation marks

Tags: linux, bash, sed

I'm kinda new to Linux and Bash.

I'm trying to replace a line with another one and i don't know how to use sed right:

old line:

```
"certificate_path": "/etc/ajenti/ajenti.pem"
```

new line:

```
"certificate_path": "/etc/nginx/ssl/xyz-combined.pem"
```

I tried:

```
sed -i '26s/.*//etc/nginx/ssl/xyz.de-combined.pem"/' /etc/ajenti/config.json
```

best regards,
Aeris

Comment: There are SO many different things this question could mean. Split on `:`? Split after space? Search for certificate_path? Search for a string containing /s? Just about anything else? [edit] your question to state your requirements.

Comment: Edit: Kenavoz's solution is working!

Comment: A script that produces the output you expect from a small sample input is the starting point to identifying a solution, not the end point. I can see a few different ways the script you say "is working" will fail given different input values. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/29613304/1745001 for more info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using sed with [backreference](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html#uh-4):

```
sed -i 's~\("certificate_path": "/etc/\)ajenti/ajenti.pem"~\1ssl/xyz-combined.pem"~' /etc/ajenti/config.json
```

The common part of old and new string is captured with brackets (`"certificate_path": "/etc/`) and prepended using backreference `\1` to the new path : `nginx/ssl/xyz-combined.pem"`.

**Edit:**

To use a variable in the replacement string, just surround the variable name with single quotes to allow parameter expansion:

```
mydomain="xyz-combined.pem"
sed -i 's~\("certificate_path": "/etc/\)ajenti/ajenti.pem"~\1ssl/'$mydomain'"~' /etc/ajenti/config.json
```

You can also surround the sed command with double quotes and escape all internal double quotes :

```
sed -i "s~\(\"certificate_path\": \"/etc/\)ajenti/ajenti.pem\"~\1ssl/$mydomain\"~" /etc/ajenti/config.json
```

Comment: Wow thanks! That's exactly what I was looking for!
Can i use a variable like: sed -i 's~\("certificate_path": "/etc/\)ajenti/ajenti.pem"~\1ssl/${MYDOMAIN}.pem"~' /etc/ajenti/config.json or do I have to modefy it?

Comment: Thanks :) Youre awesome!

Answer (score 2):

`sed` can use any character as separator for the substitution (`s`) command. In fact whatever follows `s` will be treated as a separator.

In your case, instead of escaping all slashes you can use different delimiter e.g. `#`.

```
 sed -i 's#"certificate_path": "/etc/ajenti/ajenti.pem"#"certificate_path": "/etc/nginx/ssl/xyz-combined.pem"#g' /etc/ajenti/config.json
```

Note: `g` option will replace all the occurrences of old pattern in a file. Remove it if you want to replace just first pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Simply

```
sed -i 's@/etc/ajenti/ajenti.pem@/etc/nginx/ssl/xyz-combined.pem@g' \
   /etc/ajenti/config.json
```

You don't exactly describe if there is anything else to replace.

Answer (score -2):

Looking at your problem quickly, I guess you should be escaping the slashes by using a backslash before each slash.

Tell me if that worked.

Regards,